# Materialized view to be refreshed only when the select query returns data in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

```
Create materialized view mv_testdata
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE
AS
SELECT * FROM VW_TESTDATA;
```

I want the view to be refreshed weekly once and only when the data available in `vw_testdata` view. Trying with triggers also but it didn't work.

Is it possible to refresh mv only data available in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `vw_testdata` is an "ordinary" view, it is a stored query and contains no data. I presume your concern is that - if that query (at some time) fetches "nothing" and you refresh the materialized view, you'll lose data in the materialized view.

If that's so, create a stored procedure, e.g.

```
create or replace procedure p_refresh as
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select max(1) 
    into l_cnt
    from vw_testdata
    where exists (select null from vw_testdata);

  if l_cnt = 1 then
     dbms_mview.refresh('mv_testdata');
  end if;
end;
/
```

It checks whether anything exists in `vw_testadata`; if so, it refreshes the materialized view.

Now schedule that procedure to be executed weekly.